# Как реализовать проверку введенных данных пользователем при авторизации?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Как реализовать проверку при авторизации пользователя так, чтобы если пользователь уже зарегистрирован, система авторизировала его, а не создавала новую учетную запись? Есть ли примеры простых регистрации с помощью identity? Или только с сессиями?

Мой код на asp.net mvc ..

```
public ActionResult Registration()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(UserAccount account)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.UserAccounts.Add(account);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    ModelState.Clear();
    ViewBag.Massage = account.FirstName + "" + account.LastName + "successfully registred";
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserAccount user)
{
    var usr = db.UserAccounts.Single(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.Password == user.Password);
    if (usr != null)
    {
        Session["UserID"] = usr.UserID.ToString();
        Session["UserName"] = usr.FirstName.ToString();
        return Redirect("LoggedIn");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "UserName or password is wrong");
    }
    return View();
}

public class UserAccount
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("user") { }

    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: В чем конкретно у Вас сложность в каком месте кода? Что Вы пробовали, в каком участке кода видите проблему?

Comment: у списков есть метод [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ru.stackoverflow.com Пожалуйста не торопитесь с публикацией вопроса, вначале ознакомьтесь с [краткой инструкцией](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) и допустимой [тематикой вопросов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: если речь идет о [tag:asp.net-identity-2] то поле которое является *логином* является уникальным индексом на уровне бд, т.е. создать пользователя с ***идентичным*** логином не получится, бд этого сделать не позволит, **но** возможен вариант bald **!=** bаld и т.п.

Comment: а если моя регистрации создана только с сессиями?я не использую identity так как я новичок и еще не разабрался с как работает identity

Comment: не совсем понятно что следует понимать под: *а если моя регистрации создана только с сессиями?*

Comment: при обращении к кому либо в коменте рекомендую писать ник и перед ним символ `@` вида **@Bald**  - это необходимо что бы пришла нотификация

Comment: @Bald я добавил код где указан мой класс регистрации ,,и в ActionResult Login-е я использовал сессии

Comment: раз уж используете EF то и воспользуйтесь его возможностями: добавьте индекс на поле `UserName`(это можно сделать как через fluent api так и через Data annotations) и тогда бд будет следить за уникальностью *логина*. в методе регистрации нового пользователя надо будет добавить возможность оповестить пользователя что желаемый ник уже занят

Comment: перечитал *отредактированный* вариант: при регистрации пользователя у Вас есть вся необходимая информация для проверки существования пользователя с указанными учетными данными. я бы наверно поступил так: в *перегруженную* версию метода `Registration` добавил проверку на существование пользователя с указанными учетными данными, если такой пользователь есть то тогда *авторизуем* его иначе создаем нового пользователя